# How To Disable htcCheckinService?

Tags: system, bugs, processes, system-info

This process causes CPU spikes and sometimes incredibly slows down whole system. I need to know how to disable it. Tried with **Quick System Info PRO** but it won't allow me to end process or close it.

*HTC Desire S*
*Android 2.3.5*

Comment: Have you considered flashing Cyanogenmod? This will rid of any HTC related junk.

Comment: No, it's a couple of months before my warranty expires and I am intending on doing that after.

Comment: If your device is rooted, you could check with an app like [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun) whether there is a corresponding Listener established -- and if so, deactivate that. Just a guess, I did that with other apps -- but as I flashed CM a while ago I cannot test with Sense anymore ;)